# C# Obtain Subset of a List Starting From Last Occurrence of Specific Value

Tags: c#

I have the following sample code where I am attempting to get a subset of the list starting from the last occurrence of "Start":

```
List<Sample> sampleList = new()
{
    new Sample(){ Id = 101, Action = "Start", Quantity = 1 },
    new Sample(){ Id = 105, Action = "Add", Quantity = 3 },
    new Sample(){ Id = 112, Action = "Start", Quantity = 4 },
    new Sample(){ Id = 117, Action = "Start", Quantity = 4 },
    new Sample(){ Id = 125, Action = "Add", Quantity = 2 },
    new Sample(){ Id = 133, Action = "Subtract", Quantity = 1 },
    new Sample(){ Id = 158, Action = "Subtract", Quantity = 1 }
};

int indexLatestStart = sampleList.FindLastIndex(x => x.Action == "Start");

List<Sample> newList = new();

foreach (var item in sampleList)
{
    if (item.Id >= indexLatestStart)
    {
        newList.Add(item);
    }
}
```

The resulting newList should contain the following:

```
Id = 117, Action = "Start", Quantity = 4
Id = 125, Action = "Add", Quantity = 2
Id = 133, Action = "Subtract", Quantity = 1
Id = 158, Action = "Subtract", Quantity = 1
```

Comment: Can you use LINQ or are you limited in any way?

Comment: @dropoutcoder Yes, solution using LINQ is welcome.

Comment: So.... you're not getting those values in `newList`? What's the question?

Comment: I'd iterate from end. One pass.

Answer (score 1):

The `FindLastIndex` Method return the **Position** index of the last mathed item, not his ID property.

You can change your code as:

```
int indexLatestStart = sampleList.Last(x => x.Action == "Start").Id;
```

Or you will also be based in a loop on a location:

```
for (int i = indexLatestStart; i < sampleList.Count; i++)
{
    newList.Add(sampleList[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An answer above is correct and uses the code in the question too but works if the list is sorted.

Change

```
int indexLatestStart = sampleList.FindLastIndex(x => x.Action == "Start");
```

To

```
int indexLatestStart = sampleList.Last(x => x.Action == "Start").Id;
```

and loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < sampleList.Count(); i++)
{
    if (sampleList[i].Id >= indexLatestStart)
    {
        newList.Add(sampleList[i]);
    }
}
```

Using linq

```
List<Sample> newList = sampleList.Where(c => c.Id >= indexLatestStart).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Linq only with a one liner (depending on the size of your list).
But it could look like something close to this:

```
var newList = sampleList.SkipWhile(x => x != sampleList
                        .LastOrDefault(x => x.Action == "Start"))
                        .ToList();
```

In the code above, you would skip the results until you find the latest result with the name "Start".

As mentioned in a previous response, this only works if the list is sorted. Otherwise you'd have to sort it before using this Linq sample.